# How can I include html in my shell script? Can I get html formatted output when I execute my shell script?

Tags: linux, html, bash, shell

Do we have any command which can trigger html code in shell as we  to trigger CSS in html

Comment: The shell is not a web browser.

Comment: If your question is "how do I send HTML formatted email from a bash script?", please update it to say that

Answer (score 1):

You can't render html in a shell. If you want to see how HTML in shell looks like, try installing lynx...

ANSI/VT100 terminals and terminal emulators can output colored text (and text background) using  escape sequences.

```
echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
```

outputs red text for example ..

You can get more info here: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: Can I mail the html output from shell script

Comment: as html is rendered on the client you can send it from everywhere .. maybe you can help us understand your problem by giving more information. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to format the shell output using html and send that output through mail

Comment: do you need colors? You could export it as plaintext (by piping it into a file) and display it inside a "<pre>" Tag (so keep line endings)